# What is the use of Manual IP Settings on Copy Machine which is Connected to Router with DHCP

Tags: ip, dhcp

Today, my company got a new copy machine. During configuration, copy machine guy asked me what IP address we want to use for the copy machine.

I said, "I'm gonna reserve 192.168.1.200 in DHCP settings in the router." 
And then he entered the address in the LCD screen of the copy machine.

So I asked, "what is that for?" He answered, it is for static IP.

It confused me because I can set the reserved IP for the copy machine "IN THE ROUTER" settings (NetGear ProSafe FVS336Gv3), which leads me to picture DORA process like this:

1. copy machine asks to be Discovered by DHCP server
2. DHCP server offers an IP. (here it would be reserved one if I set)
3. copy machine requests the offered one.
4. DHCP server acknowledges the request.

I find nowhere the address entered in the copy machine works!!!

What is use of the address manually entered in the copy machine if I can set it up from the router?

What happens if I set the reserved IP other than the one in the copy machine? Copy machine would reject the offered IP? hmmm....

Does the copy machine have some sort of ability to request the specific IP to DHCP server even for the case the reserved IP is not set in the router?

Can anyone shed some light on this, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> What is use of the address manually entered in the copy machine if I
>   can set it up from the router?

It's up to the device whether it uses DHCP or the statically configured one.  It's one or the other.

> What happens if I set the reserved IP other than the one in the copy
>   machine? Copy machine would reject the offered IP? hmmm....

If the machine is statically configured, it will not participate in the DHCP protocol, and will use the configured address.

> Does the copy machine have some sort of ability to request the
>   specific IP to DHCP server even for the case the reserved IP is not
>   set in the router?

No.  See the previous answer.

Comment: Reserving the address in the DHCP server will prevent it giving out the copier's address, just as one does for servers and other statically-configured hosts. Many prefer to use DHCP on the server/copier, with static, non-pool, allocations in the DHCP server, exactly as poster describes.

Comment: I thought the IP address of a device in a network is determined by its router. But you mean each device can determine its own IP in a network? Then how other devices in the same network know that address? Seems like I miss something.

Comment: @user50132 For IPv4, hosts get their IP address one of two ways:  from a DHCP server, or it is manually configured.  Routers have nothing to do with it.